# Get backend response to ajax dialogbox fails

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jsp

I have implemented ajax function inside java script function as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">


function subscriptionLookup() {

 $.ajax({
                   url:'deleteApplication?appId=9',
                   data: json,
                   type: "POST",
                   success: function (response) {
                       showMessageDialogBox(response);
                   },
                   error: function(response) {
                       showMessageDialogBox(response);

                   }

               });
 }
 </script>
```

Then I call this javascript function as follows

```
<a href="javascript:subscriptionLookup();" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete" href="#" >[Delete]</a>
```

But it gives nothing for me. I found ,  this call comes inside javascript function but not going into ajax function.

What is the problem with this

Comment: Did you load jQuery on this page?

Answer (score 1):

Well, firstly, there is a problem with your code itself. You wrote  `data: json`

In this place, you are supposed to pass information that you want to send to your server. If you want to send the word 'json', you might want to use **quotes** (just like you did with URL).

If you want to specify the data type that you want to recieve from the server, then you should remove this and instead add  `dataType: 'json'` .

I hope the answer will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You have few issue in your code. Check the modifications made.

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete" href="#" id='xxxxy' >[Delete]</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#xxxxy').on('click',function(){
        subscriptionLookup();
    });

function subscriptionLookup() {

 $.ajax({
                   url:'deleteApplication?appId=9',
                   dataType: 'json',
                   type: "POST",
                   success: function (response) {
                       showMessageDialogBox(response);
                   },
                   error: function(response) {
                       showMessageDialogBox(response);

                   }

               });
 }

});
</script>
```